# How to handle dynamic values in request_uri from nginx access logs

Tags: nginx, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail, logql

I have a PLG stack which extracts the Nginx logs (which is in json format) and visualize it in Grafana.

I want to create a dashboard in Grafana, where I get latency for different routes.

For this I am using the query:

```
min_over_time({job="nginx"}
| json
| unwrap request_time [1m])
by (request_uri)
```

But I noticed I have some routes which have dynamic values, for example `/route1/?name=adarsh`. So this route is also popping up in my dashboard which I don't want: I want it to get aggregated in into `/route1/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `| label_format` [expression](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#labels-format-expression) and `regexReplaceAll` [template function](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/template_functions/#regexreplaceall-and-regexreplaceallliteral) it is possible to introduce an additional label `sanitized_request_uri` with removed parameters:

```
min_over_time({job="nginx"}
| json
| label_format sanitized_request_uri="{{ regexReplaceAll  \"([^?]*).*\" .request_uri \"$1\" }}"
| unwrap request_time [1m])
by (sanitized_request_uri)
```

If you experiencing issues with trailing `/` in request URIs, preventing proper grouping, they can be dropped with addition of following expression

```
 | label_format sanitized_request_uri="{{ regexReplaceAll  \"(.*)/\" .sanitized_request_uri\"$1\" }}"
```

after first `label_format` expression.

Comment: it says pipeline error :-  pipeline error: 'TemplateFormatErr' for series: '{__error__="TemplateFormatErr", __error_details__="template: label:1:3: executing \"label\" at <regexReplaceAll \"[^?]*).*\" .request_uri \"$1\">: error calling regexReplaceAll: error parsing regexp: unexpected ): `[^?]*).*`",filename="/var/log/nginx/access.log", host="nginx_metrics", job="nginx", request_time="0.001", request_uri="/route1/"}'.

Comment: Use a label filter to intentionally skip this error. (e.g | __error__!="TemplateFormatErr"). To skip all potential errors you can match empty errors.(e.g __error__="") The label filter can also be specified after unwrap. (e.g | unwrap latency | __error__="" )

Comment: @adarsh, oops, missed opening `(`. Use regex `([^?]*).*` instead.

Comment: Thanks Markalex this worked like a charm !!!
just a small doubt , is it possible to add multiple regex in single query ?

Comment: @adarsh, depends on what you mean. You can definitely use `regexReplaceAll` as part of two separate `label_format` stages. Or you probably could chain them inside of a single template call. But use two separate regexes inside of a single `regexReplaceAll` - no.

Comment: If you fail to find answer yourself, feel free to ask a separate question.